# php sockets unable to connect to ssl//:443

Tags: php, sockets, curl

I have a code that checks if a website have SSL certificate as you can see below:

```
$url = "stackoverflow.com";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
var_dump($certinfo);
```

If I insert a url that contains HTTPS, this code return to me all the information about the certificate, but if I insert a url that doesn't contain HTTPS I receive the following error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client (): Unable to connect to ssl: //: 443
>   (No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.) In

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: That error indicates the remote server is not listening on or is blocking connects to port 443 (SSL port).  You need to handle that error appropriately and if you encounter it, you know the site doesn't support SSL.

Comment: Well, in this case I need to have another code to check the response of that request, and If the status code is <code>200</code> I execute my code, If not I don't execute that code and avoid the Warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the return value of [`stream_socket_client()`](http://php.net/stream_socket_client) and if it returns false not proceeding any further (because the resource is not valid).

```
$url = "stackoverflow.com";
$orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);

if (!$read) {
    // ssl connection failed for some reason
    // could be a certificate error or failure to connect on port 443
    echo "Failed to connect to site.  Error {$errno}: {$errstr}\n";
} else {
    $cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
    $certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
    var_dump($certinfo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works and now my problem is solved